# Data displayed in a DataGridView used in calculation

Tags: datagridview

I want to use a loop function to do some calculation to each row in a DataGridView.

As I have never used DataGridView before and my programming skill is very limited, I need a little bit of help.

There are five main section that I need to in this format.

1. column 2 is divided by a text box   (speed = CDbl(tbWinchSpeed.Text))
2. The calculated from 1 then has another text box value added (Delay = CDbl(tbSampleDelay.Text))
3. The calculation from 2 is then added to a time (ts = DateTimePicker1.Value) and displayed in column 3
4. The calculations from 2 is then * by a combo box:

   ```
   cmbSampleRate.Items.Add("1") 
   cmbSampleRate.Items.Add("2")
   cmbSampleRate.Items.Add("4")
   cmbSampleRate.Items.Add("8")
   ```

   Then added to column 4
5. This needs to loop to each row on the grid with an if. If column 2 is the same then add only the delay to time from the previous row, populate column 3 and then * delay by (`cmbSampleRate`) and added to column 4

I know what I need just finding it hard to get my head round the coding

Regards

Daniel

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are using C# and not using DataBinding.  And if you are using DataBinding, I don't recommend you to use it because you loose flexibility.

You can probably loop through each row and column and get or set the data that you want.

Something like this:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow dgvRow in this.invoicesDataGridView.Rows)
{
    foreach (DataGridViewColumn dgvColumn in this.invoicesDataGridView.Columns)
    {
        switch (dgvColumn.Index)
        {
            case 0: // Assuming Column 0 is the AmountPaid Column
                // Get the AmountPaid value from the DataGridView
                decimal amountPaid = Convert.ToDecimal(this.invoicesDataGridView.Rows[dgvRow.Index].Cells[dgvColumn.Index].Value);
                break;
            case 1: // ChangeDue Column
                // Set the DataGridView ChangeDue value
                this.invoicesDataGridView.Rows[dgvRow.Index].Cells[dgvColumn.Index].Value = 19.99m;                           
                break;              
        }
    }
}
```

Instead of using an **int** value like **case 0:**, you should create an **enum** type for each column and then use it on the case like this:

```
// Create enum type with the column names (This needs to be on the first lines of your code.  Out side of your function)
enum invoicesDGV { InvoiceID, CustomerID, AmountPaid, ChangeDue, InvoiceTotal };
```

then use it like this on the **switch** statement of the **foreach** loop:

```
case (int)invoicesDGV.AmountPaid: // for AmountPaid
```

instead of:

```
case 0:
```

This way if you ever add new columns to your **DataGridView** you just need to edit the **enum** type variable.

I hope this helps.